# Cross domain cookie not set when client has a port specified chrome

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, cross-domain

There are two domains: client.com and cookies.com. Client.com serves a file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Requester</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.withCredentials = true;
        request.open("POST", 'http://cookies.com');
        request.send();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And the cookies.com serves a file

```
<?php
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://client.com');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
    $i = 0;
    setcookie('A' . $i++, 'B', time() + 24 * 60 * 60, '/', '', false, false);
    setcookie('A' . $i++, 'B', time() + 24 * 60 * 60, '/', '.client.com', false, false);
```

The cookies are set, everyone is happy. But now, the client.com has to serve from client.com:3000, so cookies.com code changes into

```
<?php
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://client.com:3000');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
    $i = 0;
    setcookie('A' . $i++, 'B', time() + 24 * 60 * 60, '/', '', false, false);
    setcookie('A' . $i++, 'B', time() + 24 * 60 * 60, '/', '.client.com', false, false);
    //Just for test, but cookies don't accept ports... don't they?
    setcookie('A' . $i++, 'B', time() + 24 * 60 * 60, '/', '.client.com:3000', false, false);
```

It seems firefox accepts the domain specific cookie, however chrome doesn't.

Why is that?